# Sampling Android Speech to Text at intervals

Tags: android, text, speech

Currently the android speech to text function allows the user to speak a sentence and processes that sentence when the user pauses.

However, I'm trying to see if its possible to sample the user at various intervals, such that it listens to the user on one thread and processes the what the user previously said on another thread.

Is there a way to do this?

Ultimately, I'm trying to create an app that does not violate the user's privacy by storing all of his/her speech at once, rather only samples part of the speech, processes, then discards it, before moving on.